# Isomorphism between $\mathbb{F}^{m \times n}$ and $\mathcal{L}(V, W)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, transformation

Let $\mathbb{F}^{m \times n}$ be the vector space of all $m \times n$ matrices and let $\mathcal{L}(V, W)$ be the vector space of all linear maps from a vector space $V$ to a vector space $W$ ($V$ and $W$ both over $\mathbb{F}$) with $\dim V = n$, $\dim W = m$.  Is $M_{B_V, B_W}: \mathcal{L}(V, W) \rightarrow \mathbb{F}^{m \times n}$ an isomorphism for each choice of bases $B_V$ of $V$ and $B_W$ of $W$?

EDIT:  Sorry if this question did not seem motivated - my main reason for asking is that I am confused by matrices in $\mathbb{F}^{m \times n}$ whose entries are all the same or in which there is a repetition of columns: in other words, how can such a map be surjective?  How can an $a_{ij} \in \mathbb{F}^{m \times n}$ whose entries are all the same or in which there is a repetition of columns correspond to $B_V$ and $B_W$?

Comment: Yes, yes it is. If you'd like more details, you should begin by adding more details to your question. In particular, check out the information here about [How to ask a good question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/588/how-can-i-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese: Thanks for the advice - I edited my question.  I will make sure to take a look at that guide you linked me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathcal{L}(V, W)$ is the set of all linear maps $V \to W$, they need not be injective or surjective. The map $M_{B_VB_W}$ takes a linear map $\varphi : V \to W$ and associates to it the unique matrix $A_{\varphi} \in \mathbb{F}^{m\times n}$ such that $[\varphi(v)]_{B_W} = A_{\varphi}[v]_{B_V}$; here $[\,\cdot\,]_{B_W}$ and $[\,\cdot\,]_{B_V}$ mean the components with respect to the bases $B_W$ and $B_V$ respectively. That is, $M_{B_VB_W}(\varphi) = A_{\varphi}$. If the matrix $A_{\varphi}$ has repeated columns, that just means the map $\varphi$ is not injective.

Comment: I understand this - I am not talking about the maps in $\mathcal{L}(V, W)$.  I am talking about the map $M_{B_V,B_W}$

Comment: Okay...this makes wonderful sense.  I should have known that this is exactly what you meant in your original answer.  Thanks!